# How to add multiple .jar files in the javac/java class path - for Debian Linux

Tags: java, linux, debian

How to add multiple .jar files in the javac/java class path - for Debian Linux.

Iam using,

> javac -cp a.jar folder1\folder2\b.jar Test.java

But, it is giving Invalid flag error. Can anybody help me how to compile and run it ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Separate the class path entries by `:` colons, not spaces.

Comment: For Windows user, `;` should be used instead of `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Also you should use '/' instead of '\' as directory separator.

Answer (score 1):

Also use quotation marks " to specify a classpath when using Powershell:

```
 javac -cp ".;folder1\folder2\b.jar" Test.java
```